# API Gateway custom domain ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I followed the steps in the AWS documentation to set a custom domain for my APIs.

I have a setup with a versioned, regional API and I decided I would keep every version in a separate API Gateway API, like this:

```
test_api_v1
test_api_v2
etc.
```

I created a custom domain and the path mapping for each API as you can see below:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|           GetBasePathMappings         |
+----------+-------------+--------------+
| basePath |  restApiId  |    stage     |
+----------+-------------+--------------+
|  v2      |  api-id-v2  |  production  |
|  v1      |  api-id-v1  |  production  |
+----------+-------------+--------------+
```

Then created the corresponding record in Route53:

```
{
    "Name": "test-api.mydomain.com.",
    "Type": "CNAME",
    "AliasTarget": {
        "HostedZoneId": "Z1U9ULNL0V5AJ3",
        "DNSName": "d-abcdef1234.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com.",
        "EvaluateTargetHealth": false
    }
}
```

P.S. I also tried with an `A` record, instead of `CNAME`; results were the same.

Now the problem comes from the fact that doing `test-api.mydomain.com` a few consecutive times, I get the the record shown sometimes and sometimes nothing and the browser says `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

How can I solve this? How can I even debug it further?

Answer (score 1):

So just looking at the docs you must have the following;

> Before you get started, you need the following:
>
> An API Gateway API that has a custom domain name, such as api.example.com, that matches the name of the Route 53 record that you want to create.
>
> A registered domain name. You can use Amazon Route 53 as your domain registrar, or you can use a different registrar.
>
> Route 53 as the DNS service for the domain. If you register your domain name by using Route 53, we automatically configure Route 53 as the DNS service for the domain.

When you creating route 53 record. Specify the following values:

> Name:
>   Enter the domain name that you want to use to route traffic to your API.
>
> The API that you want to route traffic to must include a custom domain name, such as api.example.com, that matches the name of the Route 53 record.
>
> Type: Choose A – IPv4 address.
>
> Alias: Choose Yes.
>
> Alias Target: How you specify the value for Alias Target depends on whether you created the hosted zone and the API using the same AWS account or different accounts:
>
> Same account – Choose the list, and find the category API Gateway APIs. The list of target domain names includes only APIs that have a custom domain name that matches the value that you specified for Name. Choose the applicable value.
>
> Routing Policy: Choose the applicable routing policy. For more information, see Choosing a Routing Policy.
>
> Evaluate Target Health: Accept the default value of No.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I meet all the prerequisites listed in the docs. I also configured my record set within route53 exactly as described (if you look at the JSON I provided, you should see that, or maybe I missed anything?). Do you have any other idea, please?

Comment: Your json shows configuration for a CNAME not an A record.

Comment: oh sorry. I specified (right after the snippet) I had also tried with an A record. But sadly that didn’t work either.

Comment: So another suggestion is. Each Route 53 hosted zone has a separate set of name servers. Your domain should be associated with these exact name servers. Take a look at the hosted zone, grab the name servers and head over to "Registered Domains" in the Route 53 Management Console. Select your domain and you'll see the name servers associated with the domain on the details page that appears. These may not match the ones from the hosted zone. If that is the case, replace them with the name servers from the hosted zone.

Comment: my hosted zone works for any other AWS service I use (including my personal website https://www.barbu110.com). That’s why this feels so strange to me.

Comment: **NOTE**: After hitting *Create custom domain name* in API Gateway web console and configuring the custom domain, I got this domain `d-7qutsdntx9.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com`. If I browse to it, or `telnet ... 80` I get connection refused. Is that normal? Could there be a problem with AWS?

Comment: @Victor that is normal for regional endpoints -- they don't support HTTP *at all* -- only HTTPS. Try port 443.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot is that written in the docs? I just happened to get inspiration from God to do a telnet on port 443 and realize that was the problem. In any case since I didn't get to post my finding before you, please post an answer so I can accept it! Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't explain `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` which was your original question.  That would have been a DNS error.

Comment: [*"Amazon API Gateway does not support unencrypted (HTTP) endpoints."*](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/)  From memory (based on testing) I recall that regional endpoints refuse connections on port 80, while edge optimized endpoints return either a 400 or 403 error on port 80. The difference is probably nothing more interesting than a quirk of the implementations and is not specifically documented.